# sql query rails way doesn't work

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

this query doesn;t seems work

```
Project.find_by_sql("select p.name as n,u.firstname,sum(i.estimated_hours) as es,(select sum(hours) as hours from time_entries where time_entries.user_id = u.id  and time_entries.project_id = p.id) as spenthours  from users u inner join members m on (m.user_id= :id )inner join projects p on p.id = m.project_id inner join issues i on i.assigned_to_id = u.id and i.project_id = p.id group by p.id,u.id",{:id => params[:id]})
```

give me error like

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id inner join projects p on p.id = m.project_id inner join issues i on i.assign' at line 1:
```

is there any way to pass params to the find_by_sql query in rails.I tried but seems doesn't work.if there is any other suitable way then plz show me the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap `find_by_sql`'s arguments in an array:

```
Project.find_by_sql(["you_great_query_here", {:id => params[:id]}])
```

check the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class)